# Check box IF function issue

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to get my sheet to subtract a certain amount from a total for every "x" I have in the referenced cells.

My formula is:

```
=IF(G9 = "x",A8-150,A8)AND(IF(G10 = "x",A8-115,A8))AND(IF(G11= "x",A8-90.80,A8))AND(IF(G12 = "x",A8-11.02,A8))
```

I'm getting a formula parse error. Is this just a syntax issue, or am I not using the conditional statements correctly? Is there an easier way around this?

Comment: I think you might need to put the whole thing inside another set of parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try changing how you're constructing this.

From what I can see, depending on which columns have an "x", you want to subtract between zero and four values from the same column.

Maybe try something like this:

```
=A8 - (IF(G9 = "x",150,0) + IF(G10 = "x",115,0) + IF(G11= "x",90.80,0) + IF(G12 = "x",11.02,0))
```

This does the Boolean check on each of the cells in question and either returns some value (if true) or 0 (if false), then adds them all up and then subtracts from your original cell.